# Aurelia Side Navigation With Sub Items

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia application and I've got the AdminLTE theme working with it. But, I'd like to use a side navigation with top level items that expand and reveal sub items.

With Aurelia, I'm not sure what approach to take in order to do this because binding to a route only provides 1 level of navigation. Is there a way to bind multiple levels of navigation from a route collection?

For instance, my route looks like this:

```
config.map([
        { route: ['','welcome'], name: 'welcome',     moduleId: 'welcome',          nav: true,  title: 'Welcome',      auth:true, settings: {icon: 'fa fa-home'}},
                { route: '/case/',       name: 'case',        moduleId: './case/search',    nav: true,  title: 'Cases',        auth:true, settings: {icon: 'fa fa-search'}},
                { route: '/case/recent', name: 'recent-case', moduleId: './case/recent',    nav: true,  title: 'Recent Cases', auth:true, settings: {icon: 'fa fa-search'}},
                { route: '/analysis',    name: 'analysis',    moduleId: './analysis/home',  nav: true,  title: 'Analysis',     auth:true},
                { route: '/transfer',    name: 'transfer',    moduleId: './transfer/home',  nav: true,  title: 'Transfer',     auth:true},
        { route: '/auth/login',  name: 'login',       moduleId: './auth/login',     nav: false, title: 'Login'},
                { route: '/auth/logout', name: 'logout',      moduleId: './auth/logout',    nav: false, title: 'Logout' }
                ]);
```

I would like my case/recent navigation item to appear under the top level navigation item "case" in the side menu like this:

[image]

Looping over the items in the router currently is only one level, is it possible to nest routes to support more than one level of navigation?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show nested routes, you still need to have all routes even nested in router config as plain array. To show them as tree you just subscribe on `router.navigation` and transform it to needed tree using `settings` object in the way you like better.

```
<mytree source.bind="transformToTree(router.navigation)"></mytree>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What does tranformToTree do? Is that a custom converter?

Comment: It is your custom method to transform `router.navigation` to some tree you can iterate over and build menu links